# How to manage responsive text size and margin in Bootstrap

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

I have a text on top of an image with margin to put the text on the correct area on the image as in the code bellow, when I check on mobile the image is zooming out to fit the mobile screen however the text is going more to the right (keeping the margin! the margins isn't zooming out) and text size isn't zooming out.

how can  I accomplish the responsive / zoom out on mobile phone or another screen size?

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row" style="position: relative;">
 <img src="slogan.jpg" width="100%" style="z-index: -1;">
   <div class="mb-0 mb-md-3 mb-lg-0" style="z-index: 1;  position: absolute;margin-left: 300px;margin-top: 100px;">
     <p class="mainhead ">Header</p>
     <h1 class="mainh1">
            Line1 <br /> line2. <br />Line3!</h1>
   </div>
   
</div>
</div>
```

I have the meta viewport as

Comment: set `margin-left: auto;`

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen then the text will go to the left in all screen size, I need it to be on specific part of the image and scale / zoom out with the screen size

Comment: A lot of Bootstrap commands are responsive so you can specify things as you have done `mb-md-3`. Unfortunately Margins and Padding are not yet responsive and so inserting the `md` won't work. You can only do `mb-3` for example. The answer to your question is all in custom CSS.

Comment: @phpjunkies01001 look at [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Viewport_meta_tag) after adding this, it will fix your issue on mobile

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen tried to modify the viewport and still same problem

Comment: @CuteyfromCuteCode and how can this be achieved if you can give the css code?

Comment: I can't see any of your CSS so it's difficult to know but I am going to guess that using padding that has `%` or `rem` rather than `px` might work better. Eg `padding: 5%;`. The font size will be handled by your `@media` queries. Can I ask why you have added that position element to the Row? Adding CSS that relates to layout has a greater chance of confusing Bootstrap and screwing it up the more you add.